# Use modified part of file path as new file name

Tags: export, import, files-and-directories

i want to import an image, modify it and then export the modified image.

Something like this:

```
img = Import["C:\\Images\\e4271-5.jpg"]
```

Some modifications happens.

```
StringTake[img,{21,27}]
cond=StringTake[img,7]
If[cond=="5",Export["C:\\Images\\e4271-55.jpg"],Export["C:\\Images\\e4271-11.jpg"]]
```

So i'll encounter two types of files, files with file names "name-1" and files with file names "name-5". I want mathematica to import the files, modify them and save them in the same folder with nearly the same name, only difference to the filename is that for the "name-1"-ones there is an extra "1" added to the file name. Resulting in  "name-1" -> "name-11" and analoge "name-5" -> "name-55".

How do i do that? StringTake wont work because of the quotation marks with my string of interest.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a function which takes in a filepath and generates a filepath to a file with nearly the same name, but with a duplication of the final digit of the base name, then you can use `String` pattern recognition like this:

```
formatString = First@StringCases[#, x__ ~~ y_ ~~ ".jpg" :> x <> y <> y <> ".jpg"] &;
formatString@"C:\\Images\\e4271-5.jpg"
```

resulting in

> "C:\Images\e4271-55.jpg"

### Edit

I noticed that in version 10, the `x_` and `y_` show up in orange, which they didn't used to do. Normally this indicates an error, but the code executes fine. I swear there was a previous question which asked this, but I can't remember where it was. Why is this occurring?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the various `FileName` functions to get the result you want. The following function will import all the files in the folder `../images`, modifies them with the function `DoThings` and exports them with the original file name extended by the last character of the file name.

```
SetDirectory[".../images"];
Export[FileBaseName[#] <> StringTake[FileBaseName[#], -1] <> "." <> 
    FileExtension[#], DoThings[Import[#]]] & /@ FileNames[]
```